# List all files in a directory ,extra information is coming

Tags: php, opendir

here my code-

```
if ($handle = opendir('banner/')) {    
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) { 
        echo "$file"; 
    }     
    closedir($handle); 
}
```

wher I run this code unnecessary dots(.) are coming.
output `image-3.jpgimage-4.jpgimage-1.jpgimage-2.jpgimage-5.jpg...`      why 3 dots are coming at the last??

Comment: please work on you accept-rate - from the faq: When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer. This lets other people know that you have received a good answer to your question. Doing this is helpful because it shows other people that you're getting value from the community. (If you don't do this, people will often politely ask you to go back and accept answers for more of your questions!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `.` is the current directory and `..` is the parent directory.

They are always exists.

If you need to exclude them - just add

```
if ($file != '.' && $file != '..')
```

right before `echo`

Answer (score 0):

It's because there are items in your directory which you don't see... one of them is `.` and represents the current directory, and the other is `..` and represents the directory above the current one. You need to filter these out of any readdir results.